# How to evaluate functions $f, g, h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ at specific numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $f, g, h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be defined by
>   $$f(x) = -(x - 1) \\
> g(x) = 2x^2 \\
> h(x) = 3x + 1$$
>   a) What is $(f \circ h)^{-1}(3)$?

For the first one I understand this when there is no $-1$ in the function. I am not sure whether or not I need to turn the $3$ into a negative number.

> b) What is $(f \circ g \circ h)(1)$?

For the second one, what I think is the answer is:

$$h(1) = 3+1 = 4 \\
g(4) = 2(4^2) = 2(16) = 32 \\
f(32) = -(32 - 1) = -31+1 = -30$$

But I am not feeling entirely confident with that answer.

> c) What is $(h \circ h^{-1})(\pi)$?**

For the third one I'm not sure what to do in general, that one confuses me the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), you need to calculate the inverse functions, then use $(f \circ h)^{-1}=h^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$. The $-1$ signifies inverse function, not to plug in negative numbers.

(b) looks right.

For (c), inverse functions exist if and only if $(h\circ h^{-1})(x)=x$ for any $x$. Your answer is $\pi$. The functions cancel each other. (Side Note:  "inverse" trigonometric functions aren't really inverses. That's why a lot of people call them "arctangent," etc.)